Which is the nature of cognition?
What is the basis of cognition, and is there a general notion of what the mind does? Is it categorization, classification, analogy, metaphor, generalization, abstraction? It seems that all of human thought is fundamentally reducible to certain types of activities no matter what the domain. Doesn't all human thought reduce to a limited number of classes?

Pattern Matching is probably the most general description.

Could you first say whether you see the 'nature' in the Question title and the 'basis' in the exposition as the same thing? Are you suggesting either or both might provide 'a general notion of what the mind does'?
Doesn't the exposition suggest cognition, mind and thought are interchangeable terms?
How could anything in that exposition suggest all human thought reduced to a limited number of classes?

OP : "Doesn't all human thought reduce to a limited number of classes [certain types of activities]?"
Heidegger's reduction is fairly simple: thought is a type of understanding, and understanding is intrinsic to being, intrinsic to existence as a living entity, (in contrast to the objective existence of a stone). Heidegger's irreducible starting point is Dasein being-in-the-world.  The following quotes are mostly from Being & Time.

To Dasein's Being, an understanding of Being belongs. Any
understanding [Verständnis] has its Being in an act of understanding
[Verstehen]. If Being-in-the-world is a kind of Being which is
essentially befitting to Dasein, then to understand Being-in-the-world
belongs to the essential content of its understanding of Being.
H.85-6

Although being/existence is ultimately indefinable H.3-4 and incomprehensible (ref. Derrida)—as mentioned in the following quote, not "theoretically transparent" to say the least—being is known as intuited, primorially familiar.

That wherein Dasein already understands itself in this way is always
something with which it is primordially familiar. This familiarity
with the world does not necessarily require that the relations which
are con­stitutive for the world as world should be theoretically
transparent. However, the possibility of giving these relations an
explicit ontologico­-existential Interpretation, is grounded in this
familiarity with the world; and this familiarity, in turn, is
constitutive for Dasein, and goes to make up Dasein's understanding of
Being.
H.86

Stepping back to tradition, thinking is a type of knowing.

The problem of how to get appropriate access to entities
within-the­-world is one which Descartes feels no need to raise. Under
the unbroken ascendance of the traditional ontology, the way to get a
genuine grasp of what really is [des eigentlichen Seienden] has been
decided in advance: it lies in νοεῖν—'beholding' in the widest sense
[der "Anschauung" im weitesten Sinne]; διανοεῖν or 'thinking' is
just a more fully achieved form of νοεῖν and is founded upon it.
H.96

But thinking is considered derivative of understanding.

¶ 31. Being-there as Understanding
'Intuition' and 'thinking' are both derivatives of understanding, and
already rather remote ones. Even the phenomenological 'intuition of
essences' ["Wesensschau"] is grounded in existential understanding.
H.147

Notwithstanding Heraclitus

τὸ γὰρ αὐτὸ νοεῖν ἐστίν τε καὶ εἶναι, "For thinking and being are the same." p.215, fn.3

Thinking is rather a mode of being, not synonymous with it.  Being is closely bound to reason, and therefore to understanding, and then more distantly to thinking.

"Only when we contemplated what λόγος meant for Heraclitus in early
Greek thinking did it become clear that this word simultaneously names
being and ground/reason, naming both in terms of their
belonging-together." The Principle of Reason, page 112.

OP: "What is the basis of cognition, and is there a general notion of what the mind does?"
Insofar as the foregoing indicates, the basis of cognition as thinking, or even as understanding, must be being, with understanding basically intrinsic to what the mind does.
As a basis 'being' may seem obvious in retrospect, but it is characteristic of being that it makes itself transparent in day-to-day experience.
OP: "Is it categorization, classification, analogy, metaphor, generalization, abstraction?"
All of the above, no doubt.

Trial and error, also known as operant conditioning or reinforcement learning, underlies everything. You try something, you see if it works, and if so, you're more likely to do it again later. Our other cognitive habits are a result of this, apart from a few that are just purely instinctive.
A lot is wrapped up in the phrase, "see if it works." This involves a notion of scoring the outcome and then tying that score back to the specific actions that caused it. That's called the credit assignment problem.
This is also the method by which artificial neural networks (ANNs) are trained. Particularly in reinforcement learning, but also just generic backpropagation can be understood as a variation on trial-and-error. Each gradient update step moves in the direction of what works (or what would have worked a little better, had you tried it).
Of course, the brain does it better in many ways than ANNs do, often able to learn based on a self-directed goal rather than an externally imposed reward, and able to learn over very long time scales compared to ANNs.

Superior pattern processing is the essence of the evolved human brain
Mark P Mattson
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC4141622/

This article considers superior pattern processing (SPP) as the fundamental basis of most, if not all, unique features of the human brain including intelligence, language, imagination, invention, and the belief in imaginary entities such as ghosts and gods. SPP involves the electrochemical, neuronal network-based, encoding, integration, and transfer to other individuals of perceived or mentally-fabricated patterns. During human evolution, pattern processing capabilities became increasingly sophisticated as the result of expansion of the cerebral cortex, particularly the prefrontal cortex and regions involved in processing of images. Specific patterns, real or imagined, are reinforced by emotional experiences, indoctrination and even psychedelic drugs. Impaired or dysregulated SPP is fundamental to cognitive and psychiatric disorders. A broader understanding of SPP mechanisms, and their roles in normal and abnormal function of the human brain, may enable the development of interventions that reduce irrational decisions and destructive behaviors.

Embodied brain is like the Pinball Wizard:
https://youtu.be/hHc7bR6y06M
The most coherent (scientific?) model for the human brain is a neural network system that somehow (a miracle or mystery occurs here) generates mental experience as the product of a natural process. The subjective world we experience is generated locally by the brain from information arriving both from the body itself and from the surroundings. Cognition is some sort of natural process by which the body and its surroundings (broadly, the Sun-Earth relationship) generates what we experience as the subjective human mind. I refer to the ultimately mysterious source of the human experience as either The Nameless God or Psychogenesis.
